# How to return value as integer value instead of scientific value in angular js view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, numbers

I have this function to convert from dp (density independent) to px (pixels):

```
$rootScope.dp2px = function(dp) {
    if(!!dp) {
        var px = window.devicePixelRatio * dp / 160;
        return px.toPrecision(2);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The function has no error. But when I want to use the function in angularjs view like:

```
<h6 style="font-size:{{dp2px(2901.33)}}px !important; width:{{dp2px(17067)}}px !important;" ng-click="openPopoverGiftBox($event)">{{countergift}}</h6>
```

Then the output become:

```
<h6 style="font-size:17px !important; width:1.0e+2px !important;" ng-click="openPopoverGiftBox($event)" class="ng-binding">4 Jam</h6>
```

How let the value of `1.0e+2px` always `100px`?

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How let the value of `1.0e+2px` always `100px`?

You can use the Number function to achieve this:

```js
var sc = "1.0e+2";
console.log(Number(sc));
```

Answer (score 0):

toPrecision is the problem, use toFixed

Comment: Sorry, still the same result `1.0e+2`

Comment: can u check in console, whats ur function is returning?

Comment: Yes I've checked it.

Comment: toPrecision is the problem, use toFixed

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Number() function is the exactly solve my question.

Comment: in your question **"The function has no error."** is incorrect information. Your function is returning 1.0e+2